# List all layers in MXD and whether or not it is broken

Tags: arcpy, layers, data-source

I have a script that lists all layers in an MXD and I have a script that lists all broken layers in an MXD (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listbrokendatasources.htm). I want to list all layers, their name, source, description, and whether or not their source is broken. Can anyone help me with this? I can't quite figure out how to integrate the two...

```
import arcpy, os, fnmatch, csv 

#Create an empty list of ArcMap documents to process...
mxd_list=["A.mxd", "B.mxd", "C.mxd"]

for mxd in mxd_list:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
    mapPath = mxd.filePath  
    fileName = os.path.basename(mapPath)
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)  
    filepath = "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/"+ fileName[:-4]+".csv"  
    writer = csv.writer(file(filepath, 'wb'))  
    sourcelist = []  

    for layer in layers:  
        if layer.supports("dataSource"):  
            layerattributes = [layer.longName, layer.dataSource]
            #Write the attributes to the csv file...
            writer.writerow(layerattributes)  
    writer.writerow(sourcelist)  
    del writer
```

Comment: The source you linked to will list the broken sources for all layers in all maps in a folder. To clarify, are you trying to report even if the source isn't broken?

Comment: @smiller yes - I want a list of all layers, all sources, and whether or not the source is broken on each layer. The link is for a function that only takes in MXDs as an argument. I want a function to call on each layer individually, but haven't found it.

Comment: This might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150734/listing-data-sources-in-arcgis-map-mxd-without-opening-it

Comment: Or maybe this page will help. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30630/crawling-directory-and-listing-all-datasources-using-arcpy

Comment: @user88042 neither of those show me new information. My script works to list all layers in an MXd already, it just doesn't tell me if the source is broken or not. Even if a layer has a broken data source, it *has* a source that it is spitting out.

Comment: Idea: Get a list of all of the data sources as you have written above. Get a list of the broken data layers, and loop through them to get the data sources. The ones not in the latter are good sources.

Comment: The [Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) class has an `isBroken` property. You should be careful with it, since it does not reflect if the source has been broken since the last time the MXD was written. An `arcpy.Exists ()` will also be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out an easy fix: I create an array of the broken layers, then check to see if the layers in the MXD are in that array. I instruct my output to write a "yes" or "No" to determine if the layer is broken.

```
#Import necessary libraries
import arcpy, os, fnmatch, csv 

#Create an empty list of ArcMap documents to process. 
mxd_list=[r"\\...\XYZ.mxd","//computer/d$/ABC.mxd"]

#Initiate a for loop to run through each MXD in the list
for mxd in mxd_list:
    #Define the MXD
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)

    #Get the file path from the MXD
    mapPath = mxd.filePath  

    #Get the name of the MXD from the full path
    fileName = os.path.basename(mapPath)

    #Get a list of all layers in the given MXD
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)  

    #Define the output file path. Here the file is being saved to the desktop with the same name as the MXD. Change the file path to an accessible location.
    filepath = "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/"+ fileName[:-4]+".csv"  

    #Define the file to be written as a CSV.
    writer = csv.writer(file(filepath, 'wb'))  

    #Identify all broken layers in the MXD
    brknList = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)

    #Initiate a for loop to run through each layer within the MXD
    for layer in layers:  
        #Check to see if the layer supports the attribute "dataSource". Not all layers support this stored metadata value.

        if layer.supports("dataSource"): 
        #Determine if the layer is broken or not by comparing it to the list of broken layers 
            if layer in brknList:
                broken = "Yes"
            else:
                broken = "No"

            #Compile a list of layer attributes. This list can be modified based on the defined properties of the layer class in arcpy (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm).
            layerattributes = [layer.longName, layer.dataSource, broken]

            #Write the attributes to the csv file.
            writer.writerow(layerattributes)  

    #Delete variables that will be recycled in the loop
    del writer
```